# heroku eureka-js-client node- Spring Cloud Netflix Support -

Tags: node.js, heroku, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

What I want to achieve is:

- registering a node.js service in my eureka-server in heroku.

  So far i can register a regular eureka-client in my eureka-server in heroku, without problems. But i am getting really confused with the configuration when try with node.js service...

  I thought eureka-js-client was the solution, no success so far...

  Code below.

  ```
  const express = require('express');
  const path = require('path');
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3090;
  const app = express();
  app.use(express.static(__dirname));
  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'))
  });

  const Eureka = require('eureka-js-client').Eureka;

  const eureka = new Eureka({
  instance: {
  app: 'sheila',
  hostName: 'localhost',
  ipAddr: '127.0.0.1',
  statusPageUrl: 'http://localhost:5000',
  healthCheckUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/health',
  port: {
  '$': 5000,
  '@enabled': 'true',
  },
  vipAddress: 'myvip',
  dataCenterInfo: {
  '@Class': 'com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo',
  name: 'MyOwn',
  },
  },
  eureka: {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8761,
  servicePath: '/eureka/apps/',
  },
  });
  eureka.logger.level('debug');
  eureka.start(function(error){
  console.log(error || 'complete');
  });

  // ------------------ Server Config --------------------------------------------
  var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Listening at %s', port);
  });
  ```

First i've tried locally after running `docker run -it -p 8761:8761 springcloud/eureka` on my docker console. But i get this error:

```
Problem making eureka request { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8761]
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 8761 }
```

if i run it as it is from a heroku service, It does not execute  :( :(

I also tried by substituting the host for the url of my heroku eureka server, but then i get 401 or 404 errors. The eureka server requires a password which i added in my heroku client js .

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include an instanceId which should be a unique identifier of this instance.

```
const eureka = new Eureka({
  instance: {
    instanceId:'sheila',
    app: 'sheila',
    hostName: 'localhost',
    ipAddr: '127.0.0.1',
    statusPageUrl: 'http://localhost:5000',
    healthCheckUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/health',
    port: {
      '$': 5000,
      '@enabled': 'true',
    },
    vipAddress: 'myvip',
    dataCenterInfo: {
      '@Class': 'com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo',
      name: 'MyOwn',
    },
  },
  eureka: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8761,
    servicePath: '/eureka/apps/',
  },
});
```